# 'memcpy' (merging two structures)

Tags: c, networking

Consider the folowing snippet:

```
#define IPV4_MAX_BYTELEN  4
struct gen_entry
{
  struct in_addr addr;
  struct in_addr mask;
  ..
};
unsigned char key[40];

memcpy (key, &fec->addr, IPV4_MAX_BYTELEN);
memcpy (key + IPV4_MAX_BYTELEN, &fec->mask, IPV4_MAX_BYTELEN);
..
```

What I want is to merge both IP address and mask in a binary key.
Is it ok to merge it this way, provided that array size is enough for
this purpose? (or I'm missing something?)

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would normally be called "concatenate" rather than "merge".

For portability, you could explicitly use the `s_addr` field of `struct in_addr`, rather than assuming it's the first thing. Although maybe that's guaranteed by Posix, I'm not sure. I think Posix also guarantees that the `sizeof` an IPv4 address is 4 bytes, so you're OK there.

Your code doesn't clear the other 32 bytes of the array, so it can't (yet) be used as a key in any useful way. Unless `key` is defined at file scope, in which case it's initialized to zeroes.

Other than those minor niggles, I don't see anything wrong with what you're doing.

As a hypothetical portability issue - even if there are no padding *bytes* before the `s_addr` field of `struct in_addr`, if there are padding *bits* in the value then you could in theory get false negatives. Suppose you construct two keys from different sources that have the same value but different padding bits - then they should yield the same key but in fact do not. I wouldn't worry about it, though: any implementation weird enough to have padding bits in integer types is probably too weird to provide the Posix networking API.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the size of the structs.

Consider:

```
memcpy (key, &fec->addr, sizeof(fec->addr));
memcpy (key + sizeof(fec->addr), &fec->mask, sizeof(fec->mask));
```

To ensure you get all of the values in the structs.

The size of the key is `sizeof(fec->addr) + sizeof(fec->mask)`

Comment: The second memcpy would be `key + sizeof(fec->addr)`. Also be careful you missed a `>` in the first sizeof

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's OK if you want to concatenate the binary values of the first `IPV4_MAX_BYTELEN` bytes of the in_addr structs (s_addr on most systems but you'd still want to specify it explicitly).

You can even declare key as an `unsigned char [IPV4_MAX_BYTELEN*2]` if you just want those two in it.